# AutoMapper exception When converting one DTO to another object

Tags: c#, mapping, nunit, automapper

I am trying to run a test to check that my mapping is correct however every time I run the debugger I get an `AutoMapperMappingException`.

My code:

```
public BB.LMS.Models.CaseExport ConvertStarsCaseExportToCaseExport(BB.LMS.Services.Core.Models.Stars.caseexport caseExport)
{
    Mapper.CreateMap<BB.LMS.Services.Core.Models.Stars.caseexport, CaseExport>();

    var ConvertedCase = Mapper.Map<BB.LMS.Services.Core.Models.Stars.caseexport, BB.LMS.Models.CaseExport>(caseExport);
    return ConvertedCase;

}
```

and

```
[TestMethod()]
public void ConvertToCaseTest()
{
    DTOService service = new DTOService();

    caseexport export = xmlService.DeserializeStarsExport(testStarsFile);
    CaseExport convertedCase = service.ConvertStarsCaseExportToCaseExport(export);
```

Exception:

> {
>       "Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.\r\n\r\nMapping types:\r\ncase -> Case\r\nBB.LMS.Services.Core.Models.Stars.case -> BB.LMS.Models.Case\r\n\r\nDestination path:\r\nCaseExport.solicitor.solicitor.case.case\r\n\r\nSource value:\r\nBB.LMS.Services.Core.Models.Stars.case"
>   }

FIXED: As Sergey L correctly pointed out, I hadn't mapped case -> Case once that had been mapped my code worked a treat!

Comment: What's the exception? can you include it in your question?

Comment: Just added updated the question.

Comment: You should define mappings for BB.LMS.Services.Core.Models.Stars.case and other classes for your model that are used in the BB.LMS.Services.Core.Models.Stars.caseexport class.

Comment: Thank you! that was exactly the problem and it now works brilliantly. I'd been stuck on this since yesterday and I am very grateful for your help.

Answer (score 2):

The error says automapper needs configuration in order to be able to map.

Here is one way to do it :

```
    public BB.LMS.Models.CaseExport ConvertStarsCaseExportToCaseExport(BB.LMS.Services.Core.Models.Stars.caseexport caseExport)
    {
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
            {
                 cfg.CreateMap<BB.LMS.Services.Core.Models.Stars.caseexport, CaseExport>();
            });
        var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
        var ConvertedCase = mapper.Map<BB.LMS.Services.Core.Models.Stars.caseexport, BB.LMS.Models.CaseExport>(caseExport);
        return ConvertedCase;
    }
```